# ordered list number and label misaligned

Tags: html, css

I have a `label` and an `input` in an `ol` like this

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <label for="testing" style="display:inline-block;width:200px;">
      <!-- Content Here -->
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="testing" name="test" value="" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

If I add `width` to my `label`, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S4yNp/16/) is the result I get

As you can see, the first line in my `label` (starting with the first word `Donex`) is not aligned with the number 1 of my list. I want the text of my label to start on the same line as the number of my list.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283285/css-is-there-a-way-to-vertically-align-the-numbers-bullets-before-each-list-ele

Answer (score 1):

Style the label to vertical-align:top;

Comment: If I add vertical-top to my label, in the resultI get, things are not quite perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this :

```
<ol>
    <li ><label for="testing" style="width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">Donec vitae sem et purus luctus venenatis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus posuere fermentum dapibus.</label> <input  type="checkbox" name="testing" value="" /></li>
</ol>
```

Run on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4yNp/58/). Hope it will be your expected output.

Comment: The `display:inline-block;` is missing for the label element, so the width is ignored

Comment: Yes, I have discarded that.Do you need this.

Comment: Yes I need it, cause the labels can get long

Answer (score 0):

is this what look like [demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/S4yNp/40/) or this [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/S4yNp/43/)

html

```
<ol>
    <li><label for="testing">Donec vitae sem et purus luctus venenatis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus posuere fermentum dapibus.</label> <input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="" /></li>
</ol>
```

added css for demo 1

```
ol li label {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
}
```

added css for demo 2

```
ol li label {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
```

hope this help

Comment: How do I align also my checkbox to the top-right of my label in demo 1?