# How to center the list icon for an image inside a li element

Tags: html, css

```css
li{
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: circle">
        <li><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?A=B&plus;\left&space;(&space;C&plus;D&space;\right&space;)^2" height="20" width="150"></li>
    </ul>
```

As not all of the browser support MathML I use images for equations. As I adjust the height of the images I don't have a problem when I use the images in text. However I have a problem using images as a list element, the bullet icon is shown aligned with the bottom of the image.

I tried to specify the height of the `li` element the same as the `height` of the image and assign the same value to `line-height` property. After that even I use `vertical-align: middle` property it doesn't work.

What can be done to vertically center the bullet icon?

Comment: can you show a fiddle with your attempts?

Comment: I suspect this is the answer you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8283361/3369753

Comment: did you try <center> tag?

Comment: @MouhamadKawas `center` is deprecated in HTML5. We can avoid using that.

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan Fiddle is added as requested.

Comment: @SamHH It seems it does what I want I will try to understand the mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `vertical-align` the `img`:

```css
ul { list-style-type: circle; }
li { height: 20px; line-height: 20px; position:relative; }
li img { 
  height:20px; width:150px; border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: middle; /* <-- this */
}
li::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?A=B&plus;\left&space;(&space;C&plus;D&space;\right&space;)^2" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The same thing happens here, it is shown aligned a bit upper than center.

Comment: @Zalajbeg: It is in the middle only. It appears so because of the image. I have updated the snippet above, you can clearly see that it is in the middle of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `vertical-align:middle;` to the list item, add it to the image:

```
li img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ff9n9kt/)

Comment: I did it but it is shown aligned a bit upper than center.

Comment: It only appears that way because of the superscript `2` you have at the end of the image, you could add a negative `margin-top` to the image to account for that: http://jsfiddle.net/3ff9n9kt/2/

Comment: It was a great explanation. Thanks for it! It was a dilemma to decide which answer to accept, however as I think the example below will show better that the bullet is centered if someone searches on the web and comes here. I am really sad about that I cannot accept both of the answers.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image inside a div

```
li{
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
div {
   text-align: center;
}




<ul style="list-style-type: circle">
        <li><div><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?A=B&plus;\left&space;(&space;C&plus;D&space;\right&space;)^2" height="20" width="150"></div></li>
    </ul>
```