# How to line up <ol> list items?

Tags: html, css

The result I got with my list-items is this :

1 Pellentesque sed tristique. Aliqtae convallis lacus, nec mollis metus. mauris, et dictum nibh cursus sed. Integer feugiat augue sit amet enim vehicula, id vulputate leo lacinia.

(notice the text goes under the numbers)

But I want a space under those numbers how can accomplish that ? something like this

1. Pellentesque sed placerat nunc. Maecenasas. Vam tempus tincidnisl. Nullam imperdiet convallis mauris, et dictum nibh cursus sed. Integer feugiat augue sit amet enim vehicula, id vulputate leo lacinia.

http://jsfiddle.net/dndrtqo0/

```
<ol>
    <li> Pellentesque sed placerat nunc. Maecenas dignissim nec sapien sed ultricies. Nullam faucibus dolor nec enim scelerisque tristique. Aliqtae coleo lacinia. </li>
    <li> Pellentesque sed placerat nunc. Maecenasas. Vam tempus tincidunt lobortis nec quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus nec dolor semper, lacinia justo nec, pellentesque nisl. Nullam imperdiet convallis mauris, et dictum nibh cursus sed. Integer feugiat augue sit amet enim vehicula, id vulputate leo lacinia. </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: remove css u will get result

Comment: Do the numbers need background?

Comment: While the solution from @Danish works, I wanted to point that in your demo you use 'li:before' and 'counter-increment: item;'  for numbering while <ol> is already 'ordered list; and has numbering list items with digits 1.2.3.4 etc, by default; just removing it will do the trick, check this - https://jsfiddle.net/dndrtqo0/2/

Comment: Thank you guys, while all the answers work fine .. I found afelixj's answer suit me the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add negative margin to the `:before`.

```css
ol {list-style: none;
margin-left: 30px;
}
ol li:before {
width: 50px;
margin-right: 10px;
content: counter(item);
text-align: center;
background: red;
display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -65px;
 }
ol li {
margin-bottom: 30px;
counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li> Pellentesque sed placerat nunc. Maecenas dignissim nec sapien sed ultricies. Nullam faucibus dolor nec enim scelerisque tristique. Aliqtae convallis lacus, nec mollis metus. mauris, et dictum nibh cursus sed. Integer feugiat augue sit amet enim vehicula, id vulputate leo lacinia. </li>
<li> Pellentesque sed placerat nunc. Maecenasas. Vam tempus tincidunt lobortis nec quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus nec dolor semper, lacinia justo nec, pellentesque nisl. Nullam imperdiet convallis mauris, et dictum nibh cursus sed. Integer feugiat augue sit amet enim vehicula, id vulputate leo lacinia. </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css for this.

```
li
{
   margin-left:15px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table with two columns (works in all browsers):

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>1.</td>
       <td>Pellentesque sed tristique. Aliqtae convallis lacus, nec mollis metus. mauris, et dictum nibh cursus sed. Integer feugiat augue sit amet enim vehicula, id vulputate leo lacinia.</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>2.</td>
       <td>Other stuff</td> 
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Adding an entire table just to modify some spacing hardly seems like the best solution.

Comment: Yes, there will be better solutions :-)

Comment: such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283285/css-is-there-a-way-to-vertically-align-the-numbers-bullets-before-each-list-ele

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```
ol li {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ol li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: -60px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/dndrtqo0/3/